# ¿Cómo omitir un return en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Tengo una función que utilizo en más de una ocasión, dicha función retorna dos valores y en ciertas partes del código me interesa solo un valor de retorno, entonces: ¿Cómo puedo omitir alguno de los dos valores?

Sé que tengo la opción de crear una variable y asignar individualmente los return a cada variable así:

```
def funcion():

    return a, b

resultado, resultado2 = función()
#indicamos que resultado = a
#indicamos que resultado2 = b
```

Y así puedo utilizar solo un valor del return, pero ¿Hay manera de omitir un solo valor sin la creación de una variable adicional?. Sé que puedo hacer eso y nunca usar la variable pero se me hace tedioso, además que no se ve elegante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función no retorna realmente dos valores (dos objetos). En Python toda función o método retorna siempre un solo objeto (`None` si no usamos un `return` explícito). Lo que retorna realmente es una tupla (`tuple`) con dos items, con los dos valores empaquetados.

En realidad:

```
return a, b
```

es azúcar sintáctica para:

```
return (a, b)
```

Cuando haces:

```
resultado, resultado2 = función()
```

lo que haces es desempaquetar la tupla, es igual que:

```
item1, item2 = (3, 7)
```

por lo tanto, lo único que puedes hacer es:

- Seguir las convenciones de estilo y usar `_` para capturar el valor que no vas a usar:

  ```
  resultado, _ = función()
  ```

  o si fueran varios:

  ```
  resultado, *_ = función()
  ```
- Indizar sobre la tupla:

  ```
  resultado = función()[0]
  ```
- Modificar la función para que dependiendo del valor de un parámetro retorne uno solo de los valores o crear un wrapper de la misma:

  ```
  def funcion(n1, n2):
      a = n1 ** 2
      b = n2 ** 2
      return a, b

  def funcion_a(*args, **kwargs):
      return funcion(*args, **kwargs)[0]

  resultado = funcion_a(13, 27)
  ```

Comment: Esa manera de indizar no la conocía, me sirvió bastante, muchas gracias de verdad.